# Unable to load python trained model in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am getting the following errors when I am trying to load a Model, which I trained in Python, when I use the `loadModel()` function tensorflow.js:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Below is the ***predict.js*** file

```
console.log ("hello");

let model;
(async function () {
    model = await tf.loadModel("http://keras_model/model.json");
    $(".progress-bar").hide();
    console.log("it works");
})();
```

**The directory structure:**

```
main
  -dataset  (contains images for training the model) 
  -training_scripts (python scripts to train the model)
  -user_interface
     --server.js (server made using node.js(and express))
     --static (this folder contains the trained keras model)
         --index.html (html file to be served)
         --predict.js 
         --keras_model(this folder contains the model.json file)
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Your url has to be absolute if you are using `http://` as file type

Comment: Or if you are using node and want to load a local file you have to use the file type `file:///`

Comment: I am using node but i get this error. `Fetch API cannot load file:///keras_model/model.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.` Do I have to use absolute path here too??

Comment: did you require `tfjs-node`?

Comment: hey, thanks for ur help. It's working now.

Comment: I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to load local files in tfjs you need to use the file type `file:///` and for this to work you need the node extension of tfjs. You can load it by installing and requiring `node-fetch` into your program.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `fileSystem` handler exposed in tfjs-node like this:

```
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
const tfn = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const handler = tfn.io.fileSystem("./path/to/your/model.json");
const model = await tf.loadModel(handler);
```